# Spring security tags: authorize access against several parameters

Tags: java, spring-security

In JSP I need to provide a restricted access by means of Spring Security tags. The idea is to allow access to a user having role ADMIN or to a user who's principal.username is equal to a model's parameter 'email'. The tag looks like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="(principal.username).equals(${user.email}) || hasRole('ADMIN')">
```

For unknown reason it fails. The exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [(principal.username).equals(picard@gmail.com) || hasRole('ADMIN')] @34: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'bean_ref(@)'
```

I don't understand why SPEL fails because in a Controller a similar rule works just fine:

```
@PreAuthorize("(principal.username).equals(#user.email) || hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

What should I change in the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is somewhat ugly but it works

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
        <sec:authentication property="principal.username" var="username"/>
        <sec:authentication property="principal.authorities" var="auth"/>
        <c:if test="${username.equals(user.email) || auth.iterator().next().toString().equals('ROLE_ADMIN')}">
```